# Launching Play! 2.0 to point to a specific Java Installation

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have 2 separate Java installations on my machine. I have 5.0 to support an older Enterprise app I develop on, and I have the latest JVM installed for other things. I need to keep the old version on my machine, but I am now trying to use Play! 2.0 for some of my own projects.

When I try to run it from the Play! directory I get a "UnsupportedClassVersionError" since the 5.0 version is getting picked up. What is the best way to point play to my 7.0 jdk installation? It is important that JDK5 remain the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The play executable you run is a launch script that starts sbt with the Java version that is on the path. You can either change the path when you start it, like so:

```
PATH="/my/jdk7/path:$PATH" play
```

This assumes you are using some kind of unix shell. If you aren't, you can modify the launch script itself.

Comment: Thanks. The only problem with modifying the launch script is that both java and javac are used for different tasks so multiple modifications are used. I guess I was hoping for a flag that I could set when launching play. Might be something nice to have in the future.

Comment: Until then, I'll set up a script to modify my path to point to Java 7 before launching play.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean in production as in `play start`, you can run once you have compiled your application using `play dist` :

```
java -jar yourappname.jar
```

And thus specify the java version, you want to use;